# Why title remains with asterisk after executing command from iface class?

Tags: pyqgis, qgs

Why, after executing the command:

```
iface.mainWindow().findChild(QAction, 'mActionSaveProject').trigger()
```

does the title remain with the asterisk as shown in the screenshot?

[image: title bar]

Comment: Which QGIS version do you use? I tested it using the Python console in version 3.16 and the asterisk disappears.

Comment: The asterisk remains when the command is run from a test plugin, for example:

        # show the dialog
        self.dlg.show()
        # Run the dialog event loop
        result = self.dlg.exec_()
        # See if OK was pressed
        if result:

            import os
            data_dir = 'D:\qgis_sample_data\shapefiles'

            filename = 'airports.shp'
            uri = os.path.join(data_dir, filename)
            self.iface.addVectorLayer(uri, 'airports', 'ogr')
            self.iface.mainWindow().findChild( QAction, 'mActionSaveProject' ).trigger()

Comment: All right, now I was able to reproduce it. The asterisk disappears for a short time and then reappears immediately. The same happens with `actionSaveProject`. So there seems to be a change in the project after saving, but unfortunately I haven't found out what.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understood ! It is necessary to define a method that includes

```
QgsProject.instance().setDirty(False)
```

and connect this method to the *isDirtyChanged* signal

Thus:

```
QgsProject.instance().isDirtyChanged.connect(defined_method)
```

Comment: This is a nice workaround. But be aware, depending on where this signal is connected,  QGIS does not ask if unsaved changes should be saved when exiting whenever the plugin is loaded.